# Insert Current Date and Time with Custom Timestamp

Tags: org-mode, customize, time-date, customization

I am trying to get `org-mode` to insert a custom timestamp with the current time.

Something along these lines:

```
20160824 34|3 163000 (UTC)
```

Which I believe should be the following:

```
("%Y%m%d %W|%u %H%M%S (%Z)")
```

However, after editing `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` using the `Customize Browser`, I get the following:

```
Y0824 34|3 000000 (UTC
```

Issues:

1. Year does not display.
2. Current time is not displayed.
3. End parenthesis does not display.

I have read through the `org-mode` manual and searched online, but am still very lost.

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InsertingAndUpdatingDates

Comment: If I do `(format-time-string "%Y%m%d %W|%u %H%M%S (%Z)")` I get "20160824 34|3 193407 (CEST)". What happens if you just execute that snippet?

Comment: The doc-string for `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` essentially says do not change this because it will cause you problems in the future.  Just use `(insert ....)` and replace `...` with the code by @Tephra above.  The format of `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` is a cons cell with a CAR and a CDR, so that may be why you are having problems -- you need to specify one or the other -- `(car org-time-stamp-custom-formats)` or `(cdr org-time-stamp-custom-formats)` -- however, you still shouldn't mess with those values.

Comment: Thank you. Everything works fine using the shell and and executing the snippet. However, the custom timestamp via org-mode customization still does not work correctly.

Lawlist, not sure I have the emacs experience to grasp the underlying technical aspects, but I'm a bit confused as to the need to avoid customization. The manual seems to suggest that it's fine to have a custom timestamp: http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html. What am I missing?

Thanks again!